# unable to run fcntl on socket on embedded platform

Tags: linux, sockets, embedded, fcntl

I am working on an embedded platform and I'm having problems with some (seemingly) basic socket operations.
I want to open a socket and set it `O_NONBLOCK`. I came up with the following sample code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>

  char *host = "10.10.100.1";
  int port = 21;
  int control_fd = -1;
  int code;
  char *hostname;
  static struct sockaddr_in hisctladdr;

char *test(char *host, int port);

char *test(char *host, int port) {
  static char hostnamebuf[256];
  int iSockFlags;

  if (inet_aton(host, &hisctladdr.sin_addr))
  {
    hisctladdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hisctladdr.sin_port = htons(port);
    strncpy(hostnamebuf, host, sizeof(hostnamebuf));
    hostnamebuf[sizeof(hostnamebuf) - 1] = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    iprintf("Ftp::test IP dot format required\n");
    code = -1;
    return (NULL);
  }
  hostname = hostnamebuf;
  control_fd = socket(hisctladdr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (control_fd < 0)
  {
    iprintf("Ftp::test socket\n");
    code = -1;
    close(control_fd);
    control_fd = -1;
    return (NULL);
  }

  iSockFlags = fcntl(control_fd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if (iSockFlags == -1) {
    iprintf("Ftp::test : F_GETFL on %d failed, errno %d\n",control_fd,errno);
    return (NULL);
  }
  int flags = fcntl(control_fd, F_GETFL, 0);
  if (flags ==-1) {
          iprintf("Ftp::test unable to get flags, errno %d\n",errno);
          return(NULL);
  }
  iprintf("current flags 0x%x\n",flags);
  if (flags & O_NONBLOCK)
          iprintf("O_NONBLOCK already set 0x%x\n",flags);
  else {
          iprintf("set O_NONBLOCK 0x%x\n",O_NONBLOCK);
          flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
          iprintf("flags 0x%x\n",flags);
          if(fcntl(control_fd, F_SETFL, flags)<0) {
                  iprintf("Error, could not set O_NONBLOCK, errno %d\n",errno);
                  return(NULL);
          }
  }
  return (NULL);
}

void main(void){
  test(host,port);
}
```

This seems to work as expected on my PC but it doesn't seem to function the same way on the embedded target platform. On the target, I see the following message: `Ftp::test : F_GETFL on 15 failed, errno 88` and errno 88 is "*Socket operation on non-socket*".
Why might this be, I wonder?
We're running the following kernel:

```
# uname -s    
Linux
# uname -r
4.1.18-gbbe8cfc
```

on a `ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)` CPU

Per @Shawn's comment below, turns out that the `socket.h` header I'm using (`fns_socket.h`) only contains the following socket types:

```
#define SOCK_STREAM     1       /* virtual circuit */
#define SOCK_DGRAM      2       /* datagram */
#define SOCK_RAW        3       /* raw socket */
#define SOCK_RDM        4       /* reliable-delivered message */
#define SOCK_SEQPACKET  5       /* sequenced packet */
#define SOCK_PACK_EX    6       /* packet exchange non Berkeley */
```

i.e. setting the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` flag at creation, unfortunately won't work for me.

Comment: You can or `SOCK_NONBLOCK` into the type argument of `socket()` to make a new socket descriptor non-blocking from the start on Linux, btw.

Comment: @Shawn that will be a good&valid work around but doesn't explain the above, does it?

Comment: No, but if that works, it lets you do what you wanted.

Comment: @Shawn Please see the additional info i added on the bottom of my OP above.

Comment: Support for the extra socket flags was added way back in the linux 2.1 days... Unusual to see a glibc version in use that doesn't have them.

Comment: @Shawn the device is running kernel `4.1.18-gbbe8cfc` and `ldd --version`
says `ldd (EGLIBC) 2.19-2014.08-1-git` why could it possibly be missing?

Comment: @Shawn and `/lib/lib.so.6`` and `/usr/lib/libc.so.6` both say:`Compiled by GNU CC version 4.9.3 20150413 (prerelease).
Compiled on a Linux 4.0.0 system on 2015-07-23.`